# Reinstalling a godaddy certificate on node/express server?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, node.js

Copied from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35880683/reinstalling-a-godaddy-certificate-on-node-express-server)

I'm looking at a server on behalf of a client and was wondering what the cert actually is and where it comes from in this example:

```
require('https').createServer({
    key: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/something.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('/path/to/something.crt'), }, app).listen(443);
```

I know I should add this to the end of that to include my downloaded godaddy certificate bundle:

```
ca: [fs.readFileSync('./ssl/bundle_01.crt', 'utf8'),
     fs.readFileSync('./ssl/bundle_02.crt', 'utf8')]
```

1) Any idea why, in my case, I have 3 certificates in my godaddy bundle file? (gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt)

2) What is the other file that came with my godaddy download? (someHash.crt)

3) And since the old certificate has expired, do I replace the something.crt certificate? What exactly do I replace it with? Do I need to generate a new key and make a new csr request? Do I then need to download a new godaddy certificate bundle?

I'm totally new to this and am going around in circles reading other Qs and articles.

Thanks so much!

Comment: you should not cross-post. please delete your question either on stack overflow or server fault. I'd suggest deleting the stack overflow question

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about `node.js` but I can answer your questions about the certificate

1) This file `gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt` is godaddy's Root Authority Certificate (on a windows server this should be stored inside the `Intermediate Certification Authority` Certificate Folder, so your Server knows who this company is that signed your certificate)

2) `someHash.crt` is the actual certificate

3) GoDaddy normally has autorenewal for their certificates, so maybe you can just download the new certificate or you can, if you haven't got the autorenewal option, ask godaddy to renew your certificate. If you don't want to do this yes, it would be best to reassign a CSR Request, just to make sure everything works. Keep in mind that you need to buy a completely new certificate then